# Ошибка: OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен. Как исправить?

Tags: python, сокет

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я пытался написать интернет чат но все время выдает ошибку при запуске сервера:OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен. В чем может быть проблема? Вот код сервера:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind (('188.255.24.45',5943))
client = []
all_text=''
logins_passwards=['user1','password1']
logins_addres=[]
registred=[]
while 1 :
    print(all_text)
    
    try:
        data , addres = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        
            
        b=data.split()
        if  addres not in client : 
            client.append(addres)
            
            if b[0].decode(encoding='utf-8')=='register':
                if b[1].decode(encoding='utf-8') in logins_passwards:
                    index=logins_passwards.index(b[1].decode(encoding='utf-8'))  
                if b[1].decode(encoding='utf-8') in logins_passwards and logins_passwards[index+1]==b[2].decode(encoding='utf-8'):
                    registred.append(addres)
                    logins_addres.append(b[1])
                    logins_addres.append(addres)
        else:
            if addres in registred and b[0].decode(encoding='utf-8')!='register' and b[0].decode(encoding='utf-8')!='/stopserver':
                k=logins_addres.index(addres)
                all_text+='\n'+logins_addres[k-1].decode(encoding='utf-8')+': '+data.decode(encoding='utf-8')
         
        
        
        if data.decode(encoding='utf-8')=='/stopserver' and logins_addres[k]==addres:
            sock.close()
            exit()
        if data.decode(encoding='utf-8').split()[0]=='/ban':
            k=logins_addres.index(b'user1')
            k2=logins_addres.index(addres)
            if k2-k==1:
                banned=data.decode(encoding='utf-8').split()[1]
                
                
                if banned in registred:
                    banned_b=registred.index(banned)
                    registred.pop(banned_b-1)
                if banned in logins_passwards:
                    banned_a=logins_passwards.index(banned)
                    logins_passwards.pop(banned_a-1)
                    logins_passwards.pop(banned_a)
        for clients in registred :
            
            sock.sendto(all_text.encode(encoding='utf-8'),clients)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print('Подключение разорванно.')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: IP точно той машинки где запускаете? Не роутера или провайдера если машинка вдруг за NAT'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно запускать со своего не в внешнего, а внутреннего ай-пи.
Потому что внешним ай-пи распоряжается роутер.